# Javascript Output as Plain Value for Inline Style

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

I want to write the viewport width into a div inline style like so.

```
<div style="width:[viewportwidth]">stuff here</div>
```

The inline style should change as the viewport changes i.e. if I adjust the browser width, the style will change accordingly, in real-time.

I have some js that writes the viewport, but it requires an ID for document.write and thus some HTML element with that ID. I cannot figure out how to just get the viewport width in real time as the value so it can be used in a style.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  var viewportWidth = this.outerWidth;
});
```

Then you can just apply the `viewportWidth` variable to the div's style  attribute.

However, this would probably be better done with CSS `vw` units.

```
div{
   width:100vw;
}
```

This is 100% the viewport width.